# How to create a class of functions for use in another .as file?

Tags: actionscript-3

**TLDR:**
How do I make a class of functions and access them in another .as file?  Do I have to import the package, maybe?  If so, what would I put after `package`?  I tried putting in the name of the folder it is in and that didn't work.

### Create a class of functions for use in another .as file

Can someone help me out with the syntax for creating a class of functions in AS3?

I'm compartmentalizing my growing script for this project.  Many of the functions have to do with handling push,pop,shift,unshift array stuff.  So I thought I'd have a class called `ArrManagement`.  I did that which just looks like this for now:

```
package {

public class ArrManagement{

    public function ArrManagement() {

    }
    public function doStuff(){
        trace("good to go");
    }

}

}
```

Since it is just going to hold functions, I think it doesn't need to `extend` anything... correct me if I'm wrong.

The constructor is empty because I don't really want it to do anything in particular.

the `doStuff` function is obviously just filler for now.

So, this .as file is saved in the same folder as all my other .as files for this project, and they all work fine.

So I tried instantiating this class above my main document class constructor (where we declare properties using `var`) using

```
arrMan:ArrManagement = new ArrManagement();
```

and my IDE did auto complete for this class, so it is at least being recognized.  But then, elsewhere in the code I try this:

```
arrMan.doStuff();
```

and I get the following error:

**error:**

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method doStuff through a reference with static type Class.
```

and

```
1172: Definition AnimationFiles:ArrManagement could not be found.
```

Yes, in real life the function will be more complex than a simple `trace` call, but supposing I like to start simple, so supposing this *is* the function I want to use, how could I achieve this using a distinct .as file like this?

For null, who asked for a specific example, here you go:

```
    private function addAndRemoveTiles(pan:String):void
    {
        var lenRows:int = onScreenRows;
        var lenCols:int = onScreenCols;
        if (pan == "right"){
            onScreenLeftCol++;              
            // for each row
            for (var i:int = 0; i < lenRows; i++){

            //////////////////
            // remove tile from Left
            //////////////////

                // t = Tile removed from left of row
                var t:Tile = onScreenArray[i].shift();
                // tileNum = Tile Type
                var tileNum:int = tileType(t);
                // add tile from onScreenArray to arrGround
                arrGround[tileNum].push(t);

                // add Tile from left of row
                t.x = tileNum * offScreenDeckSpacingX * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckX;
                t.y = arrGround[tileNum].length * offScreenDeckSpacingY * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckY;
                addChild(t);

            /////////////
            // add tile to Right
            /////////////
                // c = right tile col (same)
                var c:int = onScreenCols + onScreenLeftCol-1;
                // cType = right tile Type (same)
                var cType:int = complexArray[i+onScreenTopRow][c];
                // t = Tile to take from arrGround
                var t:Tile = arrGround[cType][arrGround[cType].length - 1];
                // farRightTile = Tile on far right of screen (same)
                var farRightTile:Tile = onScreenArray[i][onScreenArray[i].length-1];

                // add tile from arrGround to onScreeArray
                onScreenArray[i].push(t);
                // remove tile from arrGround to onScreenArray
                arrGround[cType].pop();

                // place tile on screen
                t.x = farRightTile.x + tileWidth;
                t.y = farRightTile.y;
                addChild(t);
            }               
        } else if (pan == "left"){
            onScreenLeftCol--;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < lenRows; i++){

                // remove tile from Right
                var t:Tile = onScreenArray[i].pop();
                addChild(t);
                var tileNum:int = tileType(t);
                arrGround[tileNum].push(t);
                t.x = tileNum * offScreenDeckSpacingX * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckX;
                t.y = arrGround[tileNum].length * offScreenDeckSpacingY * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckY;

                // add tile to Left
                var c:int = onScreenLeftCol;
                var cType:int = complexArray[i+onScreenTopRow][c];
                var t:Tile = arrGround[cType][arrGround[cType].length - 1];
                var farLeftTile:Tile = onScreenArray[i][0];
                onScreenArray[i].unshift(t);
                arrGround[cType].pop();

                // place tile on Screen
                t.x = farLeftTile.x - tileWidth;
                t.y = farLeftTile.y;
                addChild(t);
            }
        } else if (pan == "down"){
            onScreenTopRow++;   

            //////////////////
            // remove tile from Top
            //////////////////
            var removedArray:Array = onScreenArray.shift();
            for (var i:int = removedArray.length; i > 0; i--){
                // t = Tile removed from top of column
                var t:Tile = removedArray[removedArray.length-1];
                // tileNum = Tile Type
                var tileNum:int = tileType(t);
                // add tile from onScreenArray to arrGround
                arrGround[tileNum].push(t);

                // add Tile from top of column
                addChild(t);
                t.x = tileNum * offScreenDeckSpacingX * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckX;
                t.y = arrGround[tileNum].length * offScreenDeckSpacingY * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckY;
                removedArray.pop();
            }       

            //add new Bottom Row
            onScreenArray.push([]);

            // for each col
            for (var i:int = 0; i < lenCols; i++){

            /////////////
            // add tile to Bottom
            /////////////

                // botRow = bottom tile row
                var botRow:int = onScreenRows-1 + onScreenTopRow;
                // tType = bottom tile Type
                var tType:int = complexArray[botRow][i+onScreenLeftCol];
                // t = Tile to take from arrGround
                var t:Tile = arrGround[tType][arrGround[tType].length - 1];
                // tile on bottom of pertinent column
                var bottomTile:Tile = onScreenArray[onScreenArray.length-2][i];

                // add tile from arrGround to onScreeArray
                onScreenArray[onScreenArray.length-1].push(t);
                // remove tile from arrGround to onScreenArray
                arrGround[tType].pop();

                // place tile on screen
                t.y = bottomTile.y + tileWidth;
                t.x = bottomTile.x;
                addChild(t);
            }
        } else if (pan == "up"){
            onScreenTopRow--;   

            //////////////////
            // remove tile from Bottom
            //////////////////
            var removedArray:Array = onScreenArray.pop();
            for (var i:int = removedArray.length; i > 0; i--){
                // t = Tile removed from bottom of column
                var t:Tile = removedArray[removedArray.length-1];
                // tileNum = Tile Type
                var tileNum:int = tileType(t);
                // add tile from onScreenArray to arrGround
                arrGround[tileNum].push(t);

                // add Tile from top of column
                addChild(t);
                t.x = tileNum * offScreenDeckSpacingX * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckX;
                t.y = arrGround[tileNum].length * offScreenDeckSpacingY * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckY;
                removedArray.pop();
            }       

            //add new Top Row
            onScreenArray.unshift([]);

            // for each col
            for (var i:int = 0; i < lenCols; i++){

            /////////////
            // add tile to Top
            /////////////

                // topRow = Top tile row
                var topRow:int = 0;
                // tType = bottom tile Type
                var tType:int = complexArray[onScreenTopRow][i+onScreenLeftCol];
                // t = Tile to take from arrGround
                var t:Tile = arrGround[tType][arrGround[tType].length - 1];
                // tile on bottom of pertinent column
                var topTile:Tile = onScreenArray[topRow+1][i];

                // add tile from arrGround to onScreeArray
                onScreenArray[topRow].push(t);
                // remove tile from arrGround to onScreenArray
                arrGround[tType].pop();

                // place tile on screen
                t.y = topTile.y - tileWidth;
                t.x = topTile.x;
                addChild(t);
            }
        }
        // put border back on top
        addChild(blockingBorder);
    }
```

Comment: Hope to do this properly actually depends on what those functions are doing and how they interact with things. So please include one or two of those functions and explain what they are doing.

Comment: Oh i see. I will post some examples in about 4 hours.

Comment: Ok, @null I added an example.  This is the main one I would like to "offload" to a separate .as file, but I'll probably tack a few more on.  Keep in mind, this is the function as it appears in my main .as file; I haven't tried to work it into a separate one because it is so big.  I figure if I can't get a simple `trace` call to work, I shouldn't tackle this huge function, yet.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: hey, null! I think I got it working.  I got my simple trace statement to work at any rate.  I think this is a duplicate question, so I'm going to delete it tomorrow.  Thanks again for looking!

Comment: Congrats for solving your problem. But why not add your solution as an answer? And yes, you want to reduce the size of that function. You might also want to look into what's called "blitting".

Comment: Thanks. I thought I *was* blitting! Each tile gets copied pixels from a tile map. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: Then why do you `addChild()` the `Tile` objects? You shouldn't have to deal with regular  `DisplayObject`s when blitting. If your code is working as expected and you want get it reviewed, maybe try asking over at [codereview.se]

Comment: Great idea. I never knew about code review. Thanks for the tip. To answer your question, I'm just doing addChild to do a quick z order fix. The tiles that get removed from the game screen get stacked in sorted piles (just a method I've been using to visually see what's happening to my arrays; addChild is not necessary for the final outcome). But you say I wouldn't have to use normal display objects... wouldn't a Sprite still be the best object to use for an interactive block (i.e. player needs to be able to collide with tiles)?

Comment: If I don't use a display object, how do the pixels get displayed?

Comment: You'd only have one `Bitmap` to display. You'd either implement collision with math or if pixel precision is necessary, you already have the ` BitmapData` of each tile. But more information and code would be necessary to give a thorough review.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Collision with math will work.  I'm basically already doing that, but simply getting the top left corner of my calculation from the "real" location of the Tile, then doing math to that point, so that will be pretty easy.  So when you say I'd just have 1 bitmap... that bitmap is simply displayed in a loader, and the loader would then be moved for panning? Or would I redraw the whole bitmap each time anything changed?

Comment: Well, I think this is already way too long of comment thread. These are all valid questions you have, so just ask them properly.